# Jquery Autocomplete not passing values to java

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jquery

I've created autocomplete with Jquery UI library and try to get the text box value in java, but not getting the value instead of getting null value. Please help to get value from text box. This is the line `String query = (String)request.getParameter("country");` not getting values ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <style>
        input {
            font-size: 120%;    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <h3>Feature</h3>
    <input type="text" id="country" name="country"/>
            <script>
        //$("#country").autocomplete("getdata.jsp");
        $("#country").autocomplete({
source: "getdata.jsp",
minLength: 2,
select: function( event, ui ) {
log( ui.item ?
"Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
"Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
}
});
    </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

getdata.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>

   <%
  String query = (String)request.getParameter("country");
  System.out.println("query"+query);
   try{
     String s[]=null;
     Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
     Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("XXXXX");
     Statement st=con.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select name from table1 where name like '"+query+"%'");
     List li = new ArrayList();
     while(rs.next())
       {
        li.add(rs.getString(1));
       }
        String[] str = new String[li.size()];
        Iterator it = li.iterator();

       int i = 0;
       while(it.hasNext())
       {
           String p = (String)it.next();
           str[i] = p;
           i++;
       }
      //jQuery related start
       int cnt=1;
       for(int j=0;j<str.length;j++)
       {
           if(str[j].toUpperCase().startsWith(query.toUpperCase()))
           {
              out.print(str[j]+"\n");
              if(cnt>=5)// 5=How many results have to show while we are typing(auto suggestions)
              break;
              cnt++;
            }
       }
    //jQuery related end
    rs.close();
st.close();
con.close();
 }
catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
 %>
```

Comment: Why did i get negative for question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not a form,so don't get the value use getParameter().

```
source: "getdata.jsp?country="+$("#country").val(),
```